# Starting Eclipse from the Unity launcher doesn't work correctly

Tags: sudo, eclipse

When I start **Eclipse** from the Unity launcher I get this message:

```
Could not find the folder 'tools' inside SDK '/home/engine/android-sdks/'
```

But when I type in the terminal

```
sudo eclipse
```

it works properly, and after running

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~
```

I got this:

```
/home/engine/.gvfs : Permission denied
```

after that I tried :

```
engine@Engine:~$ ls -al /home/engine/android-sdks/
```

and I got this :

```
total 36
drwxrwxr-x  5 engine engine  4096 Jul 31 22:17 .
drwx------ 57 engine engine 20480 Aug 11 10:26 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 engine engine  4096 Jul 31 22:17 add-ons
drwxrwxr-x  2 engine engine  4096 Jul 31 22:17 platforms
drwxrwxr-x  2 engine engine  4096 Jul 31 22:17 temp
```

thanks  **Eliah Kagan**

Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be two things going on here:

- **Ownership**: Files located in the user's home directory may be owned by `root`, when they should be owned by the user.
- **Location**: Files may be located in `root`'s home directory (`/root`) when they should be located in the user's home directory. (The OP figured this out, but accepted this answer,  so I've augmented it to include this for the benefit of others experiencing this problem.)

## Fixing Ownership

`sudo eclipse` runs Eclipse as `root`, but it still uses *your* (that is, not `root`'s) home directory to save its files. Since it runs as `root`, files it creates are *owned* by `root`, and users other than `root` cannot access them. The result is that if you've run `sudo eclipse` once, Eclipse can *only* be run via `sudo eclipse` afterwards, **until the problem is fixed.**

This is not actually a *permissions* problem, it is an *ownership* problem, and the solution is to retake ownership on the affected files and folders. It's usually safe to be the owner of *all* the files inside your home folder. So, with Eclipse *not* running, run this command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~
```

`$USER` will be expanded by the shell to your username, so you can run that command exactly as-is. Alternatively, if you want to replace `$USER` with your actual username (in this case, `engine`), that works too.

How that command works:

- [`chown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/chown.1.html) is the command for changing ownership on files and directories.
- `~` is shell shorthand for your home directory.
- `-R` means it's not just changing ownership of your home directory, but that the operation is to apply *recursively*, to all files contained anywhere within your home directory.
- The first `$USER` means you will be the owner of the files. The second `$USER` (after the `:`) means your user's group (the group created with your user account, to be the default group-owner of your files) will be the group owner.

For future reference:

- If you must run a graphical application as `root`, you should use a [graphical `sudo` frontend](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo) like [`gksu`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gksu.1.html)/[`gksudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gksudo.1.html) or [`kdesudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/kdesudo.1.html). This sets the `$HOME` environment variable to `/root`--`root`'s home directory. (It also makes a copy of [`~/.Xauthority`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man7/Xsecurity.7.html).)
- However, it's best not to run complex applications like Eclipse or Firefox as `root` at all, for security reasons. Some graphical utilities must run as `root` to work, but Eclipse is not an administration tool, and you should never need to run it as `root`. If you do, something is wrong.

## Fixing Location

As @Engine wrote:

> The problem wasn't the whole directory, but only the folder `/tools` in
>   `android-sdks`. I copied it from the root folder and then I gave my
>   user the ownerships rights with:
>
> ```
> chown -R $USER:USER ~
> ```

That is to say that, when `eclipse` had been run as `root`, it had (at least at some point) used `root`'s home directory (not the user's home directory), and the Android SDK had been stored inside `root`'s home directory.

- Either that, or the Android SDK could have been manually installed as `root` beforehand.

For the benefit of others with this problem:

- The `tools` folder can be copied from inside `/root` with:

  ```
  sudo cp -R /root/android-sdks/tools ~/android-sdks/
  ```
- Or you can *move* the `tools` folder (rather than copying) with:

  ```
  sudo mv /root/android-sdks/tools ~/android-sdks/
  ```

Then fix ownership as described above. Or, just for the relocated `tools` folder, with:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/android-sdks/tools
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I know this issue.

Check/change permissions for the folder. (Use 755.)

Comment: This is an ownership problem rather than a permissions problem. It might be possible to work around it by changing the permissions, but that would likely produce additional problems. Instead, [ownership of the files should be changed back from `root` to `engine`](http://askubuntu.com/a/174739/22949).

Comment: 755 ? sorry but I'm really new in Linux, can explainor write the full cmd :) thanks